# how to know present carry flag in assembly code?

Tags: linux

I've been reading and studying assembly code. Code is below

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08048510 <main>:
 8048510:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048514:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048517:       ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 804851a:       55                      push   %ebp
 804851b:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 804851d:       51                      push   %ecx
 804851e:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048521:       68 e0 93 04 08          push   $0x80493e0
 8048526:       68 c0 93 04 08          push   $0x80493c0
 804852b:       68 c9 93 04 08          push   $0x80493c9
 8048530:       e8 7a 07 00 00          call   8048caf <eos_printf>
 8048535:       c7 04 24 d6 93 04 08    movl   $0x80493d6,(%esp)
 804853c:       e8 6e 07 00 00          call   8048caf <eos_printf>
 8048541:       a1 38 c0 04 08          mov    0x804c038,%eax
 8048546:       bc 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esp
 804854b:       ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
 804854d:       8b 4d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
 8048550:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048552:       c7 05 34 c0 04 08 00    movl   $0x0,0x804c034
 8048559:       00 00 00
 804855c:       c9                      leave
 804855d:       8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 8048560:       c3                      ret

Disassembly of section .data:

0804c030 <_irq_mask>:
 804c030:       ff                      (bad)
 804c031:       ff                      (bad)
 804c032:       ff                      (bad)
 804c033:       ff 01                   incl   (%ecx)

0804c034 <_eflags>:
 804c034:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%eax)
        ...

0804c038 <_vector>:
 804c038:       1d 8d 04 08 1d          sbb    $0x1d08048d,%eax
 804c03d:       8d 04 08                lea    (%eax,%ecx,1),%eax
 804c040:       1d 8d 04 08 37          sbb    $0x3708048d,%eax
 804c045:       8d 04 08                lea    (%eax,%ecx,1),%eax
```

At 0x8048541, EAX register is set to 0x804c038

At 0x804854b, process jump to the address pointed by EAX register

At 0x804c048, the instruction is <  sbb     $0x1d08048d,  %eax>

By the instruction manual, sbb is stand for dest = dest - (src+carry flag). So we can replace 0x804c048 instruction to %eax = $eax - ($0x1d08048d + carry flag).

Then.... at that time, what value is set to carry flag value?
I didn't find any carry flag setting instruction previous to the 0x804c048 line. Is the carry flag is initially set to 0?

And the second question is, at 0x804854b, process jump to *%eax value. After that, how the process return to main function? there is nothing return instruction in _vector section.

I'll be glad to your help. Thanks.

Comment: At 0x8048541, eax is set to the *contents* of 0x804c038 (there's no $ in front of the operand), which is 0x8048d1d. Look there for the instruction stream.

Comment: Don't edit your question to mark it as resolved.  Instead, post an answer, and (once the timer expires) mark it as accepted, so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Oh........ @MarkPlotnick You are God to me...... I was totally trapped in the <  sbb  $0x1d08048d, %eax  >.

In the assembly source code, _vector array and _os_reset_handler function is defined as below.

```
.data
.global _vector
_vector:
    .long _os_reset_handler
    .long _os_reset_handler
    .long _os_reset_handler
    .long _os_irq_handler

.text
.global _os_reset_handler
_os_reset_handler:
    _CLI
    lea _os_init_stack_end, %esp
    call _os_initialization
    jmp _os_reset_handler

-----------------------
_CLI is defined in another c header file as macro

#define _CLI \
    movl $0, _eflags;
```

I was consistently wondering why _vector array is not contain _os_reset_handler address. I read the disassembled code again and found that the objdump misaligned the hexcode at _vector data. "0x1d (address at 0x804c03c)" didn't go to new line, so it interpreted to irrelevant assembly code. (I'm very unhappy. I didn't do any other work to catch this problem for 10 hours...)

Anyway. At the address 0x8048d1d, there is _os_reset_handler function.

```
08048d1d <_os_reset_handler>:
 8048d1d:       c7 05 34 c0 04 08 00    movl   $0x0,0x804c034
 8048d24:       00 00 00
 8048d27:       8d 25 48 d0 04 08       lea    0x804d048,%esp
 8048d2d:       e8 07 01 00 00          call   8048e39 <_os_initialization>
 8048d32:       e9 e6 ff ff ff          jmp    8048d1d <_os_reset_handler>
```

No more questions. Thanks.